# Jquery - Validating time value on a form - correct way?

Tags: jquery, validation, time, jquery-validate

After google searching, searching this site as well as [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) found there was no easy way to validate time value.

By the looks of things it suggest using [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod) and use the to regexpess the value to check against what time should look like.

However decided to look at the `jquery.validate.js` and how dateISO was checked, it looked lot easier way to do it, so I then copied all data relating to dateISO and called it timeISO and changed the string to validate time and used the following time sting

```
^([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$
```

Is there some reason why one should not modify `jquery.validate.js` and do it the way I have? Just a little bit worried as all my searching on google and this forum it was never suggested.

Comment: You shouldn't modify jQuery.validate.js because when you decide to upgrade to the latest version, you'll have to remember to update your validation code too. Treat jQuery.validate.js as 3rd party library code that should not be modified.

Comment: You can add custom methods to `jQuery.validate`, that's why it's so used. Whatever you're trying to validate, there is a custom method for it posted somewhere.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add custom methods to `jQuery.validate`. There's probably one available for this but I coded this 24h time format validation as an example:

```
$.validator.addMethod("time24", function(value, element) {
    if (!/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test(value)) return false;
    var parts = value.split(':');
    if (parts[0] > 23 || parts[1] > 59 || parts[2] > 59) return false;
    return true;
}, "Invalid time format.");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/UPjqf/1/)

[Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#examples).

You can also sum it up in a single regular expression ([source](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-time-in-24-hours-format-with-regular-expression/)):

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2}
```

And if you're using HTML5, you can use the `pattern` attribute:

```
<input type="text" pattern="([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2}" 
    required="required" placeholder="hh:mm:ss" />
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/6uwFp/)

Keep using the `jQuery.validate` method if you need compatibility with older browsers though:

```
$.validator.addMethod("time24", function(value, element) {
    return /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2}$/.test(value);
}, "Invalid time format.");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/UPjqf/2/)

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a while, but I think the best solution is to check the **additional-methods.js** library.
(You can download it from http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

There are two validations: **"time12h"** and **"time"**.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the plugin core makes it more difficult to update to a new version of the plugin, without replacing your modifications, and is rarely a good idea.

I'd suggest that you place your custom code in a separate file, instead of altering the core code.

Comment: so I could copy the changes I made and create a custoemr script currently to validate time i have the followig code "Time: { required: true, timeISO: true}, -what would i need to put it there for it to use an external js file? cheers

Comment: @Damien-Data Yes, given that the license allow you to copy code, that would be the best way to go I believe!